# Genshi - how to print out all variables in scope

Tags: genshi

Quite simply I'd like to print out all variables that are in scope in my genshi template, as a debugging and discovery measure.  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Python function [locals()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) (which returns a dict) works for me. I'm using Genshi 0.5.1, and as you'll see, everything seems to be in `__data__`.

```
${repr(locals())}
```